# Hide soft Keyboard on every onClick event

Tags: android, view, onclicklistener

I used an abstract class to implement `OnClickListener`,

```
public abstract class HideKeyboardClickListener extends View implements View.OnClickListener {

    public HideKeyboardClickListener(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setOnClickListener(this);
        AppUtils.hideKeyboard((Activity) context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    }
}
```

and used it like -

```
button.setOnClickListener(new HideKeyboardClickListener(mActivity) {
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
  // Handle Click
 }
});
```

But I am not receiving any click events.

Comment: If you use a parent activity, and implemens onClickListener on it.. and then extend this activity to all activity, then it will surely work.

Comment: Then I have to change the whole code.

Comment: no, yon dont need to change whole code.. you only need to extend that parent activity..

Answer (score 1):

Step 1.
// First create a BaseActivity class just like shown below. no need to add this in your menifest.

```
public class MyBaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        //call method to hide keyboard
    }
}
```

Step 2.
//Then extent this activity class in all Activity class like this..

```
public class HomeActivity extends MyBaseActivity {
}
```

These two steps are sufficient for what you want.. and it will not affect your application

Answer (score 0):

Put this code on your Button click

```
            InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager)
            getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); 

inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(),
               InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this method

```
 public static void hideKeyboard(Context context, View view) {
        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getApplicationWindowToken(), 0);
    }
```